# Mongo DB Combining $First and $last Results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have dataset something like this

```
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Tex-Mex" }, "RestaruntCount" : 53 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Bakery" }, "RestaruntCount" : 221 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Soups & Sandwiches" }, "RestaruntCount" : 44 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Vietnamese/Cambodian/Malaysia" }, "RestaruntCount" : 38 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Filipino" }, "RestaruntCount" : 5 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Egyptian" }, "RestaruntCount" : 5 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Nuts/Confectionary" }, "RestaruntCount" : 4 }
```

From this data set, I need to get the highest and the lowest cuisine type count in  borough Manhattan . I know that I need to get this using **$first** and **$last** but I am unable to proceed with it.

for the moment I achieved this output from the below mentioned query:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate(    [      { $match: { "borough": "Manhattan"  } },     { $group: {_id: {borough:"$borough", cuisine: "$cuisine"}, count : { $sum : 1} } },  {$sort: {count:1,_id:1}}     ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below aggregation:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "_id.borough": "Manhattan" }
    },
    {
        $sort: { RestaruntCount: 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {borough:"$borough", cuisine: "$cuisine"},
            first: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
            last: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
])
```

You can use special variable `$$ROOT` to capture entire document during aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
What if I dont want to search the entire document . say there is multiple values for borough , for each set of borough I need to find the highest number and lowest .
I need to apply to the given grouping not to the entire document ?

Comment: @FabTrex just to clarify, could you show me expected result it that case ?

Comment: { "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Bakery" }, "RestaruntCount" : 221 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "Nuts/Confectionary" }, "RestaruntCount" : 4 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Brooklyn", "cuisine" : "Vietnamese/Cambodian/Malaysia" }, "RestaruntCount" : 40 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Brooklyn", "cuisine" : "Filipino" }, "RestaruntCount" : 5 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Newyork", "cuisine" : "Indian" }, "RestaruntCount" : 5 }
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Newyork", "cuisine" : "Chinese" }, "RestaruntCount" : 1 }

Comment: Something like this .. Highest and Lowest number of resturants counts borough wise and cusinetype wise

Comment: @FabTrex I'm not sure if I understand correctly but I think you have to use `{borough:"$borough", cuisine: "$cuisine"}` as a grouping _id.